# Console Warning Due to passing additional irrelevant props to material ui Autocomple via Formik Field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

The Warning I am receiving is
[image]

I am attaching a code sandbox link reproducing this warning. Can someone explain why this warning is occurring and how to get rid of it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-bogdan-6lyxs?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is not really related to the formik Field, but the implementation of your `FormikAutocomplete` component.

In your FormikAutocomplete you're destructuring the props:

```js
const FormikAutocomplete = ({ textFieldProps, ...props }) => { ...
```

Therefore the `props` object will include `istesting` with the value `true` and `test` with your `testFunc`.  You are than spreading the `props` object into the props of material uis `Autocomplete` component, which doesn't know how to handle those props and is probably passing them on to the html element which is rendered (a div in this case). Your browser is than complaining about these props on the `div`, because they don't belong there.

The fix would be to only pass those props along to the `Autocomplete` which are propperly handled by it or destructure the props out of your `props` object which shouldn't be passed along.

You could for example change the code in your `FormikAutocomplete` to

```js
const FormikAutocomplete = ({ textFieldProps, istesting, test, ...props }) => {
...

  if (istesting) {
    test();
  }
...
}
``
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it. It was a pretty simple thing I missed. I will change the title to the post so that it can be more helpful to other people